# More on replacements in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

Most likely this is trivial, but I can't understand why through a "regular expression" search like:

```
::.*?::
```

in cases like this works:

```
::hello::
```

while in cases like this it doesn't work:

```
::hello
::
```

Is it possible to write a `regex` that works in both cases? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a check mark at the bottom of search/replace window for `.` to match new lines. Otherwise regular expression dot does not include new line matching.

Comment: As is often the case, I got there two seconds after submitting the question. Thank you for the confirmation!